# SEO friendly URL rewriting with strange format

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I recently needed to perform a manual joomla update :(

Now all pages except home have links which are incorrect and link to strange urls, it is working like this:

When I am on

http://www.example.org/index.php/foo and I click a link for "bar" the link leads to http://www.example.orgfoo/index.php/bar

What would cause this? - where would one look to find the rules which dictate how the URL rewrite is occurring.

Some Background:

I encountered a problem which interrupted my joomla update halfway through, it then wouldn't load the administrator end.

I manually installed the latest Joomla and followed instructions to fix database errors. The only page which is displaying correctly is the home page. The rest appear to have no template styling applied. When I turn off SEO friendly urls all pages work as expected.

Comment: My guess would be that your `.htaccess` file has been damaged. Add the contents of this file to your question.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, shortly after I posted this I rechecked the .htacess file and everything there is correctly set. The problem had to do with the SEO friendly rewriting plugin not being updated with the manual install.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Okay guys - basically the Joomla URL rewriting uses a plugin which appears to have been not updated. I downloaded the latest version of Joomla, merged the new "plugin" folder with my old "plugin" folder and everything is working well.